# Difference between '-save' and '--save' in `npm install`

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I've been using Node.js for six months and I still don't understand difference between `npm install pkg -save` and `npm install pkg --save`. What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, and in fact for neither of them does anything anymore. `npm install` saves what you install to `package.json` by default and has done for years, you have to use `--no-save` if you don't want it to do that (or `--save-dev` or one of the other flags). As a result, these three commands do exactly the same thing:

```
npm install foo
npm install foo -save
npm install foo --save
```

---

Any time you have a question about the command line of a tool, you can usually get the answer by using `-help` or `--help`. In this case, for instance:

```
$ npm install --help
npm install (with no args, in package dir)
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<tag>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<version>
npm install [<@scope>/]<pkg>@<version range>
npm install <folder>
npm install <tarball file>
npm install <tarball url>
npm install <git:// url>
npm install <github username>/<github project>

aliases: i, isntall, add
common options: [--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional] [--save-exact] [--no-save]
```

But that wouldn't tell you about `-save` and `--save` because they're not listed anymore. :-)